# Has anyone successfully build Bruce Eckels' 'Thinking in java' 4th Edition using Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Does anyone know how to build Bruce eckels' Thinking in java files to run on Eclipse. And can explain it in a clear way. I've been trying for days now, using stackoverflow but to no avail. Has anyone done it? Thank you.

Comment: What specific problems are you having?

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesnt answer your question completely, but there are two things you need to understand:

- it uses Ant to build
- if you look inside the 'build.xml' for the code, you will notice that if the JDK you are using is not SE5, the build fails.

There is a python file attached with the code, Eclipse.py. Running it will convert the entire code to be imported into Eclipse.

Alternatively, if you prefer Maven and want to work on JDK8, I have a project at  https://github.com/gauravojha/tij4-maven which you can clone and simply import the code as a new Maven project. But do note that there is an open issue with the 'annotations' package.